# Newgeometry changes all document

Tags: geometry, input, landscape

I am trying to set different margins for some pages of my Thesis. Essentially, I want some pages to have larger margins, since they contain big tables. I use the \input command to include big Tables in my document. I have tried \newgeometry, at the beginning of each table, and \restoregeometry at the end of each table, but Latex changes the margins of ALL my document. My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, english, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter1}
Introduction to the damn big Table.
\include{tab1}
\end{document}
```

My file tab1 is coded as:

```
\newgeometry{left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=4cm}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{centering}
{\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{l|ccc|ccc|ccc|ccc}
A & very & big & table & that & I & need & to & fit & in & the & page & ! \\
\end{longtable}
\end{centering}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When I comment out the `\include` line, my margins don't change.  So I'm not sure I understand the problem.  (also, you have a stray left brace just prior to `\scriptsize`).  Can you check the MWE you posted to see whether it exhibits the wrong behavior?

Comment: I can see nothing strange. You should use `\input` rather than `\include`; remove `\begin{centering}` and `\end{centering}` that do nothing. Also the `{` before `\scriptsize` is to be removed. Are you sure `\newgeometry` is the best way? I'm not.

Comment: I removed the stray left brace (it was just a typo), and added the package     pdflscape.
I have compiled the file again and I am sure the margins change in the whole document. I mean, it is not a big change, but if you save the two pdf's and compare them, margins are different. If you can suggest me a different way to handle this, please do.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being confusing, but I have compiled the file again. Actually, margins are wrong in both versions of the document (with and without \include). I don't know what happened. 
The thing is that I have an old pdf version of my thesis, saved before I used the package geometry, and margins are different. Now, even if I comment out all tables for which I want different margins, my pdf has the "new" margins. Is it possible that I am doing something wrong with the option [a4paper] in the preamble?

Comment: If you invoke `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`, the `pass` option leaves all prior margins intact while still giving you access to the `geometry` package's features.