# How to use both margins of the page when using align?

Tags: equations

I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}



\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Reactions}

\begin{align}
\texttt{MediumGen} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Adding}} \texttt{SalMediumStart},\\
\texttt{MediumGen} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Removing}} \varnothing,\\
\texttt{SalMediumStart} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{FirstLanding}} \texttt{SalCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{TakeOff}} \texttt{SalMedium},\\
\texttt{SalMedium} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Landing}} \texttt{SalCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Initiation}} \texttt{SalRuffle} +  \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} + \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Joining}} \texttt{SalRuffle} + \texttt{NrRuffle} +  \texttt{CapCellSurf},\\
4 \, \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{CapBeingReached}} 4 \, \texttt{NrRuffle}.
\end{align}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Now, the equations shown in the page tend to be on the right of the page, and the left margin is not used. How can I force LaTeX to use both margins and equations to be centered in the middle of the page. Here is the screenshot my problem:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your output shows you have used align incorrectly probably no &

Comment: @Thom when asking people to correct your code it helps if you show it rather than make people guess what you have done

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using. As it stands, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @Thom try `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}`, seems to fix on my system

Comment: My apologies, I forgot about the numbers

Comment: wow! not only did you not show any source you clipped the output image to make it appear flush right when in fact it is flush left and wider than the page!!! I do not think anyone would have guessed an answer to your original. The image you show is not from the posted code though, which [makes this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDtEV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using the [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to change the page margins to 2cm:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % <---------- Added


\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Reactions}

\begin{align}
\texttt{MediumGen} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Adding}} \texttt{SalMediumStart},\\
\texttt{MediumGen} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Removing}} \varnothing,\\
\texttt{SalMediumStart} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{FirstLanding}} \texttt{SalCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{TakeOff}} \texttt{SalMedium},\\
\texttt{SalMedium} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Landing}} \texttt{SalCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Initiation}} \texttt{SalRuffle} +  \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} + \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Joining}} \texttt{SalRuffle} + \texttt{NrRuffle} +  \texttt{CapCellSurf},\\
4 \, \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{CapBeingReached}} 4 \, \texttt{NrRuffle}.
\end{align}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Your contents are quite long, other then changing the page dimensions I am not sure how to force the contents to fit per line, I am posting this answer just because it works with your posted code.

---

To change geometry for just a section, use `\newgeometry` and then `\restoregeometry` afterwards like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry} % <---------- https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214820/273733
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test page}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage



\begin{appendices}
\newgeometry{margin=2cm}
\section{Reactions}

\begin{align}
\texttt{MediumGen} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Adding}} \texttt{SalMediumStart},\\
\texttt{MediumGen} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Removing}} \varnothing,\\
\texttt{SalMediumStart} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{FirstLanding}} \texttt{SalCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{TakeOff}} \texttt{SalMedium},\\
\texttt{SalMedium} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Landing}} \texttt{SalCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Initiation}} \texttt{SalRuffle} +  \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf},\\
\texttt{SalCellSurf} + \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{Joining}} \texttt{SalRuffle} + \texttt{NrRuffle} +  \texttt{CapCellSurf},\\
4 \, \texttt{NrRuffle} + \texttt{CapCellSurf} &\xrightarrow{\texttt{CapBeingReached}} 4 \, \texttt{NrRuffle}.
\end{align}
\restoregeometry
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Thom updated my answer

Comment: Are you putting `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` within `\begin{appendices}`? Not sure if it'll make a difference, difficult to help with your main document though when we do not have access to it, I have only tried to answer your MWE question sorry.

Comment: Glad it helped, I just edited that question into this answer, good find :)

Answer (score 1):

With the standard text width you need to split the terms across rows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed
%\usepackage{amsmath}% loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}% not needed
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Reactions}

\begin{align}
\mathtt{MediumGen}
  &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Adding}}
  \mathtt{SalMediumStart},
\\
\mathtt{MediumGen}
   &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Removing}}
   \varnothing,
\\
\mathtt{SalMediumStart}
  &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{FirstLanding}}
  \mathtt{SalCellSurf},
\\
\mathtt{SalCellSurf}
  &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{TakeOff}}
  \mathtt{SalMedium},
\\
\mathtt{SalMedium}
  &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Landing}}
  \mathtt{SalCellSurf},
\\
\mathtt{SalCellSurf} + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
  &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Initiation}}
  \begin{multlined}
    \mathtt{SalRuffle} +  \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ + \mathtt{CapCellSurf},
  \end{multlined}
\\
\begin{multlined}
  \mathtt{SalCellSurf} + \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
\end{multlined}
  &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Joining}}
  \begin{multlined}
    \mathtt{SalRuffle} + \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ +  \mathtt{CapCellSurf},
  \end{multlined}
\\
4 \, \mathtt{NrRuffle} + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
  &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{CapBeingReached}}
  4 \, \mathtt{NrRuffle}.
\end{align}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd consider left alignment, though.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed
%\usepackage{amsmath}% loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}% not needed
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Reactions}

\begin{align}
&\mathtt{MediumGen}
  \xrightarrow{\mathtt{Adding}}
  \mathtt{SalMediumStart},
\\
&\mathtt{MediumGen}
   \xrightarrow{\mathtt{Removing}}
   \varnothing,
\\
&\mathtt{SalMediumStart}
  \xrightarrow{\mathtt{FirstLanding}}
  \mathtt{SalCellSurf},
\\
&\mathtt{SalCellSurf}
  \xrightarrow{\mathtt{TakeOff}}
  \mathtt{SalMedium},
\\
&\mathtt{SalMedium}
  \xrightarrow{\mathtt{Landing}}
  \mathtt{SalCellSurf},
\\
&\mathtt{SalCellSurf} + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
  \xrightarrow{\mathtt{Initiation}}
  \begin{multlined}
    \mathtt{SalRuffle} +  \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ + \mathtt{CapCellSurf},
  \end{multlined}
\\
&\begin{multlined}
  \mathtt{SalCellSurf} + \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
\end{multlined}
  \xrightarrow{\mathtt{Joining}}
  \begin{multlined}
    \mathtt{SalRuffle} + \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ +  \mathtt{CapCellSurf},
  \end{multlined}
\\
&4 \, \mathtt{NrRuffle} + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
  \xrightarrow{\mathtt{CapBeingReached}}
  4 \, \mathtt{NrRuffle}.
\end{align}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering whether the `Reactions` module of the `chemmacros` package could be used in this case as well. That module is based on the `align` environment and in combination with `chemformula` offers a lot of tweaking the typesetting and such. Unfortunately it turned out that the use of `multlined` results in a lot of errors. Probably due to the way the content of the `reactions` environment is parsed using the `\ch{}` macro of `chemformula`.

Nonetheless, I like to offer this MWE as an alternative option.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[modules={reactions}]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\ttfamily}
\chemsetup[reactions]{before-tag = \textbf, tag-open = [ , tag-close = ]}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} % can be used to set greek mapping in chemmacros

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed
%\usepackage{amsmath}% loaded by mathtools
%\usepackage{mathtools} % loaded by chemmacros
%\usepackage{amsfonts}% not needed
%\usepackage{amssymb} % using mathdesign as alternative
%\usepackage{adjustbox} % not needed in this example
%\usepackage{multirow}  & ibid
\usepackage{appendix}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{appendices}

        \section{Reactions}
        
        This section contains the original answer by egreg to the posed question:
        
        \begin{align}
            \mathtt{MediumGen}
            &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Adding}}
            \mathtt{SalMediumStart},
            \\
            \mathtt{MediumGen}
            &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Removing}}
            \varnothing,
            \\
            \mathtt{SalMediumStart}
            &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{FirstLanding}}
            \mathtt{SalCellSurf},
            \\
            \mathtt{SalCellSurf}
            &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{TakeOff}}
            \mathtt{SalMedium},
            \\
            \mathtt{SalMedium}
            &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Landing}}
            \mathtt{SalCellSurf},
            \\
            \mathtt{SalCellSurf} + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
            &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Initiation}}
            \begin{multlined}
                \mathtt{SalRuffle} +  \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ + \mathtt{CapCellSurf},
            \end{multlined}
            \\
            \begin{multlined}
                \mathtt{SalCellSurf} + \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
            \end{multlined}
            &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{Joining}}
            \begin{multlined}
                \mathtt{SalRuffle} + \mathtt{NrRuffle} \\ +  \mathtt{CapCellSurf},
            \end{multlined}
            \\
            4 \, \mathtt{NrRuffle} + \mathtt{CapCellSurf}
            &\xrightarrow{\mathtt{CapBeingReached}}
            4 \, \mathtt{NrRuffle}.
        \end{align}
    
    \section{Alternative reactions}
    
    This section uses the Reactions module of the chemmacros package. Unfortunately that module doesn't allow the use of the multlined environment.
    
    \begin{reactions}
        MediumGen   &->[Adding] SalMediumStart, 
        \\
        MediumGen   &->[Removing]   \varnothing, 
        \\
        SalMediumStart  &->[FirstLanding]   SalCellSurf,
        \\
        SalCellSurf &->[TakeOff]    SalMedium,
        \\
        SalMedium   &->[Landing]    SalCellSurf,
        \\
        SalCellSurf + CapCellSurf &->[Initiation]   
%       \begin{multlined}
            SalRuffle +  NrRuffle  + CapCellSurf,
%       \end{multlined}
        \\
%       \begin{multlined}
        SalCellSurf + NrRuffle  + CapCellSurf
%       \end{multlined}
        &->[Joining]
%       \begin{multlined}
            SalRuffle + NrRuffle  +  CapCellSurf,
%       \end{multlined}
        \\
        4 \, NrRuffle + CapCellSurf &->[CapBeingReached]    4 \, NrRuffle.
    \end{reactions}
        
    \end{appendices}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Reaction_ttfamily]

Comment: Comparing the superscripts above the arrows I find those in the second  section better readable than those in the first section.